# How to animate one of the children from a Row or column widget to another Row or column in Flutter

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-layout, flutter-animation

I have 2 StatefulWidget, a Row and a Column. Each widget has some 5 to 6 children. when one of the child widget in the column is clicked, a widget in the row should move to the column widget as a child. This moving should be animated as a SlideTrasition. Again when the same child widget in the column is clicked, the already moved widget that's currently in the column should move back to the row in its original position with reverse animation.

What i tried:
I initially got the position of the widget that's going to move from the row, and the position where its going to be in the column via RenderBox.localToGlobal() from the widget's key, and stored the Offset object in the root widget which holds the row and column through inherited widget.

But now, since the widget that i intend to animate has to move from one parent to another, in this case a row to column and vice versa, the Animation  set to SlideTransition will not work. Since i presume all the animations can work only within its parent. That is move from one position to another in the same parent. I'm stuck here on how to proceed further. That is, how to animate one of the children of a row by moving it to a Column with a simple slide transition animation.

Comment: A little late but would you be able to use a [AnimatedList](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/AnimatedList-class.html) instead of a Row?